# Stop web application after upgrade

Tags: 2013, central-administration, upgrade

I've upgraded to SharePoint Foundation 2013 from a SharePoint 2007 (via SharePoint 2010).

Now I've three web application started on my server and I would like to stop previous SharePoint web application to save resources and because they are not used anymore.

This is my scenario:
[image]
The first one on the list is the SP 2013.

Is possible to stop the old web applications? Is it useful to save resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will save the resource , To stop web application.

- Open IIS > Application pool > Application Pool > Stop Application pool of your web application.

If you don't use the web application anymore , try to delete it (IIS /Content Database)  from

- Central administration > Application Management > Manage Web APllication Select your web application > From the above ribbon delete.